# time input in angular material design

Tags: angular, material-design, angular6, angular-material-6

I'm working with Angular 5 and material library. I need to use time input , but in the documentation, i didn't found an explanation to accomplish this task.  Is anybody that have same need that can suggest me a good tutorial or documentation?  Tnx

Comment: Material Angular does not have a time component.

Answer (score 0):

Use type="time" in your matinput tag
ex code:

```
<input type="time" matInput placeholder="enter time">
```